# split a string to build an object

Tags: javascript

I have a character string

```
 var str = 'initial.parentId=&initial.childId=431&initial.testProduit=BRU&initial.number=123';
```

and I would like to build the following object :

```
var data = {
         parentId: ,
         childId: 431,
         testProduit: BRU,
         number: 123
     }
```

i think the best solution would be to use the split function but i can't find the best way to do it.

If you have a solution, I'm interested

Comment: please add your code, you tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz there is no code because i have no real solution i could throw an incorrect code but in what interest

Comment: You didn't even split your string ?

Comment: Have you tried splitting it normally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to get a collection of key-value from the query string. Then loop thorough the collection and create an object

```js
const str = 'initial.parentId=&initial.childId=431&initial.testProduit=BRU&initial.number=123',
      param = new URLSearchParams(str),
      output = {}

for (const [k, v] of param) {
  output[k.split(".").pop()] = v
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```js
    var str = 'initial.parentId=&initial.childId=431&initial.testProduit=BRU&initial.number=123';
    let output={};
    str.split("&").forEach(item=>{
     let out=item.split(".").pop().split("=");
     output[out[0]]=out[1];
    })
    console.log(output);
```